# Tree for ChildNode of childNode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

i have this simple html:

```
<div id="tree">
    <div class="roi">
        <ul>
            <li>text1</li>
            <li>text2</li>
            <li>text3
                <ul>
                    <li>insideText1<li>
                    <li>insideText2<li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get only the item "text2" and the item "insideText2";
so I tried to wrote:

```
var Tree=document.getElementById("tree").document.getElementsByTagName("UL");
```

But I don't know how to reach the specific `li` that contains:"text2" and "insideText2".
Please help.

Comment: Provided a link to a working jsfiddle where required list items and child lists are extrated from the nodelist as you needed it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one document object, so you're almost there with `var Tree=document.getElementById("tree").document.getElementsByTagName("UL");`, just drop the second `document`:

```
var Tree=document.getElementById("tree").getElementsByTagName('ul');
```

Tried it out in chrome console, on this page

```
document.getElementById('question').getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Worked like a charm

**Update**

That's easy... the `getElementsByTagName()` method returns a nodeList (which is more than just any old array). The above code provides a list of all `ul` elements within the element that has the 'ul' tag. You could either loop through all `ul` tags in the list, and check for `li` children that contain an undordered list, or a certain innerText/innerHTML. I'll bash out a quick example in a minute for you.

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bsg83/1/) for a working example. play around with it as much as you want, let me know if there's still something not entirely clear to you... cheers

Comment: yes, but this is still not help me, please read what i asked in the question. Thanks

Comment: I think you will miss something,but i expected for the example
and then i will let you know if it solve my problem
Thanks.

Comment: added the example, with a crude way of selecting various child elements based on their innerHTML values, or there position in the tree. As far as I can tell, that's what you needed, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming JQuery

```
//text2
alert($('div#tree ul > li:eq(1)').text())

//insideText2
alert($('div#tree ul > li > ul li:eq(1)').text())​
```

Comment: i forgot to mention important thing,
the solution should be without jqury, only pure of javascript!.

Comment: Then you should not put jquery tag for the Question!

Comment: i need help with this guys, how do i do it with pure javascript ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to gain access to the "text2" li then use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1]
```

and the item "insideText2" would be

```
document.getElementsByTagName('li')[2].getElementsByTagName('li')[1]
```